# Visual C# ~ Get string from URL after some time

Tags: c#, http

I'm trying to get the HTML from an URL as a string. That went well, however, the site uses javascript to load some information that will be printed to the site as HTML after a few seconds. Therefore, the WebRequest won't get the information I'm trying to parse from the URL, since it's returning the HTML as soon as it reaches the site.

Is there any way you can stay on the site for a few seconds, then get the HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way for you to get that text since to get the effect of that JavaScript code, *you would actually have to execute the code*.

Any basic HTTP class library simply downloads documents from the web server, they don't execute JavaScript code.

To get what you want you will basically have to use/implement a web browser for this. Your program can use the WebBrowser component, and grab DOM trees from it after the JavaScript code has rendered the final content.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your request for the page does not execute the JavaScript.  Your best bet would be to load the page into a WebBrowser control, then after a time scrape the page in from the DOM.

Another option, if you're more concerned about the information return from the JavaScript would be to look at the page, analyze the JavaScript, and then just call that portion on your own in a second call.